# Como traduzir "snack attack"?

Tags: palavra-para-ideia, tradução

A tradução literal "ataque de lanchinhos" me soa bastante infantil e, apesar de a frase estar sendo dita por um adolescente, gorducho e comilão, não é essa a idéia que eu quero passar.

Mas eu não encontrei outras referências que não fossem literais ou muito distorcidas.

Conforme solicitado, o exemplo:

*Considerem como cenário dois adolescentes caminhando já há algum tempo e, como dito, um deles come tanto quanto um Hobbit do Condado (o.O):*

> Hang on, I'm feeling a snack attack

Comment: Esse ataque de lanchinhos é tradução literal. Quer dizer sentir uma vontade forte de comer alguma coisa fora da hora de refeição. Também, é uma especie de jogo de palavras com sneak attack, ataque sorpresa. Deve ter alguma giria por aí para a ideia. Outra coisa, não acredito que seja uma expressão "feita".

Comment: Bom, snack attack é a mesma coisa que: get the munchies, expressão muito mais antiga.

Comment: Em PT europeu, é frequente usar-se "estar com a larica" para ter fome, mas a acção pode ser "petiscar". A questão é que "snack attack" é de facto mais jovial. Em Portugal, para algumas pessoas, "petiscar" pode ser algo muito sério! :D

Comment: @Joum "estar com a larica" (ou "estar de larica") também é usada no Brasil.

Comment: larica  = fome de maconheiro

Comment: Bruno, deves incluir na pergunta a definição da expressão que queres traduzir para português ("snack attack"). Idealmente, deves também incluir um exemplo de uso.

Comment: Seria aquele ataque de comida que aparece em filmes nos refeitórios de escolas?

Comment: @Bruno Augusto Sim, senti uma vontade tremenda de SORVETE. É por aí mesmo. Sim,  larica. petiscar, não. petiscar é ficar comendo aos pouquinhos algo. snack attack é estar com a larica [de repente]

Comment: @Joum Isto pode ser o meio em que eu cresci, mas *larica* para mim é uma fome relativamente ligeira. Nunca ouvi ninguém dizer, *"Tou com uma larica, que era capaz de comer um rinoceronte"* ou *"Tou esganado de larica"*, que é o que *snack attack* me sugere; aqui diria mesmo *fome*.

Comment: @Jacinto eu sim, sempre ouvi "larica" com noção de imensidão. "*Estou cá com uma larica!*" (Mas sem aumentativos, que larica já dá esse sentido.)

Comment: @ANeves Pois, talvez seja só em Maxialês que *larica* é assim só uma "fomeca".

Comment: "Me deu uma fome agora"; "estou morrendo de fome". "estou com uma fome daquelas"

Comment: Para o exemplo: "Gente, estou com uma baita fome!", "Gente, me deu uma baita fome agora!"

Comment: Então e o [xeidafome](http://www.anilact.pt/images/conteudos/outros/danio.jpg)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Snack attack* é uma súbita e imperiosa vontade de comer, como se vê nas explicações do Lambie, livros no Google Books, e nas respostas mais votadas no [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Snack%20attack). A expressão parece ser gíria recente, tanto que nem a encontrei em mais nenhum dicionário.

Em português, com o mesmo significado e tom informal, poderíamos dizer ***ataque de fome*** ou ***ataque de gula***. *Gula* sugere vontade de comer por se ter visto algo apetitoso ou se ser guloso, não necessariamente por se ter fome. É uma questão de ser escolher a expressão mais apropriada ao contexto. Por exemplo, podeíamos traduzir assim (na linguagem coloquial de Portugal) o primeiro exemplo do [Urban Dictionary:](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Snack%20attack)

> *You: “Hey, where did all the cereal go?!”*
>   *Me: “Oh sorry dude, I had a major snack attack last night.”*
>
> *Tu:  “Eh! que é que aconteceu aos cereais?!”*
>   *Eu: “Eh pá, desculpa lá, tive um sério ataque de fome ontem à noite.”*

Ambas as expressões estão em uso. Exemplos (ênfase minha):

> Planeje se reabastecer em até 1 hora após treinos mais intensos, para dar energia aos músculos e não ter um **ataque de fome** mais tarde. [(Exame, 2014.)](http://exame.abril.com.br/estilo-de-vida/conheca-os-erros-que-podem-te-impedir-de-emagrecer/)
>
> O grande segredo é não passar um período longo sem comer, pois eles acabam gerando um **ataque de fome** — e uma pessoa com muita fome tende a comer mais e não ligar se a comida é saudável ou não. [(Blog MadeInNatural, 2015.)](http://blog.madeinnatural.com.br/saude/alimentacao-de-3-em-3-horas-entenda-sua-importancia-e-como-conseguir-manter-esse-habito/)
>
> Um dos maiores problemas para quem tem problemas de excesso de peso são os **ataques de fome** em determinadas alturas do dia [(Barriga Lisa.)](https://barrigalisa.pt/saiba-como-controlar-os-ataques-de-fome/)
>
> Quem nunca sofreu um **ataque de gula** e foi direto para a geladeira em busca de algo bem gostoso - e encontrou o que queria? [(minhavida, 2016.)](http://www.minhavida.com.br/alimentacao/testes/15446-sua-geladeira-e-de-gordo-ou-magro)
>
> Mas em teoria você pode deixar eles na geladeira por semanas, e ir usando como quiser, em saladas, entradas, petiscos, molhos, acompanhamentos ou num **ataque de gula** à noite.
>   [(Eu já comi.)](http://www.eujacomi.com.br/confit-tomate-uva-sweet-grape/)

---

Qualquer destas expressões se compreende lindamente, mas o que eu habitualmente digo e ouço dizer em vez de *ter um ataque de fome* é simplesmente, ***deu-me uma fome!*** Pelo que vi na net, no Brasil é, ***me deu uma fome!*** Agora isto para ser verdadeiramente expressivo tem de ser dito com uma entoação especial que eu não consigo reproduzir por escrito. Além disso, *ataque de fome/gula* é um sintagma nominal tal como *snack attack*, o que encaixará normalmente melhor na tradução; mas é uma questão a ver caso a caso.

Comment: O que eu queria mesmo era não usar a palavra **ataque** por se tratarem apens de crianças caminhando. Queria algo mais leve... Acho que cabe uma piadinha, até mesmo por conta da personalidade extrovertida da personagem. Sua resposta foi a que mais se aproximou daquilo que eu já tinha em mente.

Comment: @Bruno, não queres incluir na pergunta uma frase-exemplo para nós vermos melhor que expressões é ficam lá bem? Por exemplo, se no original fosse *"I'm having such a snack attack, I could eat an elephant"*, eu poderia dizer, *"deu-me uma fome, que era capaz de comer um elefante"*. Mas se fosse *"Mum is having snack attacks again"*, já teria de ser diferente.

Comment: *Roger that* ;)

Comment: @Bruno, para mim o mais próximo em significado e tom do teu exemplo é mesmo *"estou tendo um ataque de fome"*, e eu já ouvi adolescentes, e mesmo crianças, dizer coisas trinta vezes mais pesadas. Mas se queres evitar *ataque*, que tal uma tradução mais livre? *"Me deu uma fome daquelas!", "Me deu uma fome, que comeria um elefante!", "Preciso urgentemente de reabastecer", "O meu estômago está berrando de fome"*. Do tipo de *snack attack*, mas sem *ataque*, agora só me lembro de *acesso de fome*, mas *ataque* parece-me mais típico de linguagem de adolescente que *acesso*.

Comment: "minha barriga está doendo/roncando de fome"

Answer (score 3):

Fui investigar um pouco sobre isto e encontrei uma definição que me parece apropriada para [snack attack](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Snack%20attack) (e sim, entendo que a fonte não é propriamente autoritária):

> having the munchies; being very hungry and in need of something to
> snack on; ravenously and wildly getting something to eat.

Ainda assim, diria que o sentido é bastante figurado.
Penso que não há um equivalente figurado em português (pelo menos europeu, e que eu conheça/lembre).

A pesquisa bateu em **lambujar** como verbo que represente a acção. Definição via [Priberam](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/LAMBUJAR):

> Comer gulodices ou guloseimas.

No entanto, não posso dizer que tenha pessoalmente usado ou ouvido usar muito esta palavra.

Por outro lado, **petiscar**, que é bastante frequente, embora não seja propriamente figurado (ou jovial, como disse no meu comentário), tem a seguinte definição no [Priberam](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/petiscar):

> Saborear; comer pouco; provar

Mas se tivermos em conta que **petisco** é ([Priberam](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/petisco)):

> Comida muito apetitosa

Parece-me que **petiscar** é uma tradução adequada.

Por outro lado **snack attack**, sendo sinónimo de **having the munchies** também pode ser traduzido para **estar com a larica** ([Priberam](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/larica))

> [Informal] Estar com fome

E aí o uso poderia ser algo do género:

> Last night I had a major snack attack.
>
> Noite passada estava cheio de larica.

Comment: Não conhecia lambujar, acho que nunca ouvi essa palavra antes. Conhecia lambuzar, que tem um significado diferente.

Comment: Não é se lambuzar de tanto comer?

Comment: Embora não tenha encontrado referências penso que _lambuzar_ e _lambujar_ devem ser sinónimos.

Answer (score 1):

**"Snack attack"** é uma forma de **"binge eating"**, que em português significa **"episódio de compulsão alimentar"**.

Se esses episódios forem recorrentes, eles preencherão o critério para o uso do termo **"bulimia"**.   A bulimia é comum em certos distúrbios psiquiátricos, principalmente na anorexia nervosa, onde é frequentemente seguida de vômitos para aliviar o sentimento de culpa.

Os termos que cito acima são técnicos, e certamente existem formas mais populares de se dizer o mesmo.

> - [**compulsão alimentar**](http://www.alimentacaosaudavel.org/Compulsao-Alimentar.html) é um transtorno alimentar comum, em que um indivíduo consome regularmente uma grande quantidade de comida de uma vez só
> - [**Bulimia**](https://www.significados.com.br/bulimia/) é um transtorno alimentar que leva a pessoa a exagerar na ingestão de alimentos e logo a seguir provocar o vômito, ou ainda fazer uso de outros recursos como tomar laxante, ficar um longo período sem se alimentar ou praticar exercícios físicos em excesso, para impedir o ganho de peso.

**"Acesso de hiperfagia"** é um sinônimo para **"episódio de compulsão alimentar"**.

Comment: Não é verdade que snack attack significa binge eating.

Comment: Não queria colocar nada técnico, afinal são suas (quase) crianças conversando. Talvez... "fominha", como em `Sinto uma fominha chegando`. Ou teria algo melhor?

Comment: @    "me soa bastante infantil" e "não é essa a idéia que eu quero passar" fizeram com que eu interpretasse errado o tipo de expressão que procuras.

Comment: @Lambie  O termo "binge eating" engloba episódios repetidos de "snack attack", entre outras coisas.  Eu não disse que são sinônimos.

Comment: @Lambie   The urban dictionary defines "snack attack", as "when one experiences a sudden impulse to binge on the nearest foods."

Comment: @Yes, fine, but normal people binge, not all "binging" has anything to do with the bulimia or "pathological" uncontrollable impulses.  Acho que é um erro de interpretação. Binge attack é a mesma coisa que "get the munchies". An urge to stuff up on something can happen to anybody. Pregnant women, for instance. Or, you could be at the beach, and have a sudden urge to eat ice cream, and eat too much of it. That is not  a pathology.

Comment: [conceitos](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjnmN6fqaTSAhXjzVQKHXQlDokQFggnMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.urbandictionary.com%2Fdefine.php%3Fterm%3DSnack%2520attack&usg=AFQjCNHRLzay6ugvz9uR-qgruvug-s08pQ&sig2=lcwI7tLObkmeipl22LjAcA) Pelo que entendi existem dois conceitos, sendo um de rápida compulsão alimentar; ou também ataque literal com comida.

Comment: @Lambie separei mais explicitamente os conceitos de "binge eating" dos de bulimia, na resposta. Achas que assim a resposta evita as tuas críticas?

Comment: @Centaurus Snack attack não são "episódios". E gíria para dizer: sinto vontade de comer um MONTE de batata frita agora mesmo!. Por exemplo. A expressão em si usado pelos jovens quer dizer isso.